# ASP.NET Core Route Attributes - ID and hyphenated slug separated by a hyphen

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to configure the following url structure for one of my controller actions via the Route attribute:

> /products/12345-purest-green-widgets

Here's my route as it stands:

```
[Route(@"/products/{id:int}-{slug:regex([[\w\-]]+)}")]
public ContentResult Show(int id, string slug)
```

This doesn't match the intended route, but it does match:

> /products/12345-purest

and also matches with a trailing hyphen after one word, as soon as I add anything else it doesn't match.

Interestingly if I swap out the string literal hyphen (not the regex ones) for a /, it works fine in its entirety:

```
[Route(@"/products/{id:int}/{slug:regex([[\w\-]]+)}")]
public ContentResult Show(int id, string slug)
```

successfully matching:

> /products/12345/purest-green-widgets

So it seems to be tripping on the string literal hyphen. Any ideas?

Comment: Try `[Route("products/{id:int}-{*slug:regex([[\w\-]]+)}")]`

Comment: @Nkosi: That should work, but won't it make any restrictions and everything that follows after obsolete? Dunno about ops exact requirements

Comment: @Tseng I'm trying to understand what you meant by `but won't it make any restrictions and everything that follows after obsolete?` could you reword it? I'm not sure what you meant

Comment: `{*slug}` takes everything after the id, which makes the regex constraint and any parameters which come after not to be mapped. May work in that special case, doubt it will if the OP decides to put mandatory or optional parameters after the slug. Though I didn't tried it yet. Docs say `The article route parameter is defined as a catch-all by the appearance of an asterix * before the route parameter name. Catch-all route parameters capture the remainder of the URL path, and can also match the empty string.` Notice it says remainder of the url not remainder of the segment

Comment: @Tseng, ok now i understand what you meant. Yes I saw the same in the documentation. Not sure about the how the constraint would affect the catch-all. I'll have to run some tests to see.

Comment: why not just: [Route(@"/products/{id:int}/{slug}")]

Comment: Do you plan to have forward slashes in the slug part or it will always look like `12345-purest-green-widgets`? Because if thats the case you could just use two regular parameters as in `[Route(@"/products/{id:int}-{slug:regex([[\w\-]]+)}")]`

Comment: @Nikosi - that gives me: Error: A path segment that contains more than one section, such as a literal section or a parameter, cannot contain a catch-all parameter.

Comment: @GoloisMouelet Id prefer to have id-slug than id/slug - but worst case scenario that's what I'll have to do.

Comment: @DanielJ.G. The slug will always be just \w and - but your proposed route looks identical to what I have?

Comment: You are absolutely right it's the same than you have! After reading through the comments I mistakenly assumed your original route had `*slug`

Comment: It's quite interesting, I did some tests and with your original route `@"/products/{id:int}-{slug:regex([[\w\-]]+)}"`, the regex constraint isnt even evaluated for urls like `123-product-foo`, only for `123-product` or `123-product-`. I would love to understand what's going on!

Comment: Ok, with url segments like `123-product-foo` it seems the definition of the url template is **greedy** and will actually interpret `213-product` as the id paramater, which won't match the `int` constraint. Unless there is a way of defining non greedy route templates, you might need to use a different template or a single parameter with a regex for the whole `number-text` pattern, which you would manually split. (action filters might help with the split)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you dig under the hood, you will find that the Routing middleware is greedily splitting complex route segments like `{id:int}-{name:regex([[\w\-]]+)}` even before applying the route constraints. (Happens both using route attributes and the route table in Startup)

This means:

- With url like `products/123-foo`, the route matches `123` as id and `foo` as name. It will then apply the constraints, finding a match as `123` is a valid int and `foo` matches the regex.
- With url like `products/123-foo-`, the route matches `123` as id and `foo-` as name. It will then apply the constraints, finding a match again.
- With url like `products/123-foo-bar`, the route matches `123-foo` as id and `bar` as name. It will then apply the constraints, but this time it will fail as `123-foo` is not a valid int!

You don't have this issue if you split the parameters in different route segments as in `{id:int}/{name:regex([[\w\-]]+)}`, as the `/` will split the parameters right as you would expect them to.

If your route really needs to have that shape, I would then use a single parameter in the route constraint. This parameter would wrap both the id and the name:

```
[Route(@"/products/{combined:regex(^[[\d]]+-[[\w\-]]+$)}")]
```

The problem is that you would then need to manually extract the id and name from that single parameter.

- You could manually do that inside the controller action. For a one off this might be acceptable
- You could create an ActionFilter and split the combined route parameter into action parameters before the action is executed (overriding `OnActionExecuting`). This still quite hacky, specially my quick and dirty version:

  ```
  public class SplitProductParametersActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
  {
      private static Regex combinedRegex = new Regex(@"^([\d]+)-([\w\-]+)$");
      public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
      {
          var combined = context.RouteData.Values["combined"].ToString();
          var match = combinedRegex.Match(combined);
          if (match.Success)
          {
              context.ActionArguments.Add("id", int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value));
              context.ActionArguments.Add("name", match.Groups[2].Value);
          }
      }
  }

  [Route(@"/products/{combined:regex(^[[\d]]+-[[\w\-]]+$)}")]
  [SplitProductParametersActionFilter]
  public IActionResult Contact(int id, string name)
  {
  }
  ```
- You could create a new model binder with its model binder provider and some annotation attribute for your parameters. This might be the cleanest as it is similar to the approach above but extended MVC in the expected way regarding model binding, however I havent had time to explore it:

  ```
  [Route(@"/products/{combined:regex(^[[\d]]+-[[\w\-]]+$)}")]
  public IActionResult Contact([FromUrlProduct("combined")]int id, [FromUrlProduct("combined")]string name)
  {
  }
  ```

---

In order to debug the route constraints, you can set the logging as debugging and you should see a message like this in the console (you might need to run the app from the console with `dotnet run` instead of using ISS from VS):

```
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteConstraintMatcher[1]
      => RequestId:0HKVJG96H1RQE RequestPath:/products/1-foo-bar
      Route value '1-foo' with key 'id' did not match the constraint 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Constraints.IntRouteConstraint'.
```

You can also manually copy the [int route constraint](https://github.com/aspnet/Routing/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing/Constraints/IntRouteConstraint.cs) and registered it in Startup after `services.AddMvc()` with `services.Configure<RouteOptions>(opts => opts.ConstraintMap.Add("customint", typeof(CustomIntRouteConstraint)))`

An approach like the one described [in this blog](https://blog.markvincze.com/matching-route-templates-manually-in-asp-net-core/) might also help with debugging.

Comment: Wow Daniel, a lot of effort has gone in here, thank you for investigating! It seems like this might be a pretty common problem for people to run into, would it therefore be considered a bit of a bug that the int param is greedy? I had also tried to define it as a regex but didn't have any more luck that way. At the moment I'm going with the combined pattern approach and parsing out the individual values, a bit hacky as you say but there doesn't seem to be an overly clean way of doing it.

Comment: It might be worth opening an issue in the [Routing](https://github.com/aspnet/Routing) repo (actually, I havent check if this was discussed there). I was surprised by this behavior too and the scenario might be common enough

Comment: I found this post because I am having the same issue building a similar route. I opened an [issue on github](https://github.com/aspnet/Routing/issues/412)

Answer (score 0):

Very late to answer but the Id Hypenating could be removed if we rectify the default maproute in startup.cs

Change

```
routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                   template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        )
```

to the following

```
routes.MapRoute(
                        name: "default",
                       template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
            )
```

After this any route created won't be Controller/Action/4 but would be Controller/Action?Id=5